# Potion effects on armor

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to give anyone wearing a diamond helmet named “scuba” the potion effects night vision and water breathing.

What would be the command(s) to achieve this effect on Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I searched, the only thing that *would* allow you to do This is the NBT argument in target selectors(@e,@a,@r,@p,@s) which is only available on Java edition, so sadly no, you can't achieve this effect on the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use /enchant. However, on some consoles and computers it doesn't work.

Full list [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/enchant_command.php).
based on the version/console, how to use it is different. How to use each command is also on the website above.